# Launch workflow with custom action doesn't work properly

Tags: 2010, workflow, custom-actions

I've created 3 custom actions (with the type "display ribbon") for one list.

I have 3 workflows and I want each action to launch one workflow.

[image]

I want "Nettoyer" to use the "Enlèvement_clean" workflow :

[image]

But I click "OK" and when I click on the custom action, the "enlèvement" workflow is selected :

[image]

And I tried for the 3 actions and that's the same thing. All 3 actions have "Enlèvement" even if I just put another workflow.

Thanks,

Comment: Are you using more than 1 content type?

Comment: No I didn't touch the content type and I can see in the content types window that I have "folder" and "element", with "element" by default

Comment: Do I need one content type by action?

Comment: No, you should be fine with one. If you had more than one, I can imagine it might behave like this. It was just a theory.